# Springs and Cantilevers - how linear and repeatable are they under deformation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, material-science

I know you guys only deal with the ideal, but in practice how linear and repeatable is the response of a spring or cantilever when deformed under a test mass?

Comment: "How long is a piece of string?"

Comment: This depends greatly on how much they are deformed. The boundary between 'elastic' and 'plastic' response of materials is mostly an engineering one. So, if you look up the 'elastic' range of an engineering alloy in a handbook, that typically means that the material will cycle back and forth nicely and have a plastic deformation below, say, 0.1%. Note that this is not zero. If you stay well below the elastic 'limit', and have cycled the material often enough to get rid of initial plastic deformation, yet avoid creep, it should be pretty linear and repeatable. Lots of caveats there...

Comment: @JonCuster Like one part per million repeatable?

Comment: I don't think I would trust much of any mechanical system at the ppm level without some sort of measurement and feedback. That would be equivalent to a ~1 degree change in temperature (depending on the material of course).